Why No Variable Declarations in Boolean Expressions in C?
I am studying C programming from K&R, and while experimenting with the example programs, I came across this code snippet:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){                                                               
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}

and made a slight modification:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    while((int c = getchar()) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}

I expected the getchar() function to be executed first, returning an int value that would be stored in the integer variable c, and subsequently, the c != EOF expression would be evaluated. However, it appears that this is not the case. Can someone explain why that's not how it works?

Why you think that int c definition can be done in every point you want? Especially in K&R C. Your initial expectations are correct.

In printf("%d", a = 5);  a = 5 operation is executed and the value at 'a' (which is 5) is printed on the console. So i thought something like int c = d might also work

If reading K&R, you can check the appendix on syntax, and see that Expressions and Declarations are totally separate sections. You just cannot mix them.

a=5 is an assignment expression. int c=d; is a declaration with an initializer. int c=d without the trailing comma is neither a valid declaration nor an expression.

@BoP Thanks for the advice and for clarifying.

I believe this is also one spot where C and C++ are different, because C++ would have allowed something like while(int c = getchar()) but not while((int c = getchar()) != EOF)

In C, declarations are for informing the compiler about what an identifier (a name) means. They specify that a name is a variable of a certain type or is a name for a type or is a tag for a structure, and so on.
Expressions are for specifying the computation of a value.
They are separate things. Declarations are not subparts of expressions. You cannot use a declaration in the test condition of an if statement.
(There are limited opportunities to use “type names” in expressions, such as in the operand of a sizeof expression, and these type names may declare structures, unions, enumerations, and their members. These are not full declarations and cannot declare variables.)

It would be more correctly to write " Nonetheless, they are not variable declarations."  Because in particularly you can for example declare a structure type.

The only place you can have a declaration as part of a control structure is in a for loop:

selection-statement:
    if ( expression ) secondary-block
    if ( expression ) secondary-block else secondary-block
    switch ( expression ) secondary-block

iteration-statement:
    while ( expression ) statement
    do statement while ( expression ) ;
    for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
    for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement

where a declaration is one of:

declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
    attribute-specifier-sequence declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list ;
    static_assert-declaration
    attribute-declaration

static_assert-declaration:
    static_assert ( constant-expression , string-literal ) ;
    static_assert ( constant-expression ) ;

attribute-declaration:
    attribute-specifier-sequence ;

C 2024 pre-publication draft
As you can see, all forms of a declaration must be terminated by a ; -- pretty much the only place you can do that is as part of the initial expression in a for loop (which is why there's no ; between the declaration and expression in the grammar above; that's provided as part of the declaration).  There's just no other place where you can shoehorn a declaration in without radically changing the grammar.
